# ArcGIS - Suggest returning result but find not finding result?

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I have done a bit of searching but have not found anything like what I am seeing when using ArcGIS Rest API. My setup is pretty much what is suggested on the documentation... I make a call to the suggest REST endpoint with text which returns a handful of suggestions that contain the one I am looking for. When the find REST endpoint is called with the magickey and text it returns an partial address (has everything except the street number). Below is my example:

```
https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?Category=Street%20Address&f=json&text=5%20Barron%20Way,%20E
```

Which returns this JSON

```
{"suggestions":[{"text":"5 Barron Way, Eastman, Georgia, USA","magicKey":"GST7YMc0AM9UOsE3GY8tIS9GOghnYnwZGZpkJiyzCP9_JR52GZbtGSyJAnyUns8t7hc0YQWMYcyGnsxuIM9aYMTMCRhvSoauJoFF","isCollection":false},{"text":"5 Barron Way, Evergreen, Montana, USA","magicKey":"GST7YMc0AM9UOsE3GY8tIS9GOghnYnwZGZpkJiyzCP9_JR52GZbtGSyJAnyUnsNt7hc0YQWMYcyGnsxuIM9aYMTMCRhvSoauJoFF","isCollection":false},{"text":"5 Barron Way, Everman, Texas, USA","magicKey":"GST7YMc0AM9UOsE3GY8tIS9GOghnYnwZGZpkJiyzCP9_JR52GZbtGSyJAnyUnsbt7hc0YQWMYcyGnsxuIM9aYMTMCRhvSoauJoFF","isCollection":false},{"text":"5 Barron Way, Exford, Victoria, AUS","magicKey":"GST7YMc0AM9UOsEm7jbtIS9GOghnYnwZGZpkJiyzCP9_JR52GZbtGSyJAnyUnskt7hc0YQWMYcyGnsxuIM9aYMTMCRhvSoauJoFF","isCollection":false}]}
```

The first suggestion is selected which triggers a call to the following find endpoint

```
https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?magicKey=GST7YMc0AM9UOsE3GY8tIS9GOghnYnwZGZpkJiyzCP9_JR52GZbtGSyJAnyUns8t7hc0YQWMYcyGnsxuIM9aYMTMCRhvSoauJoFF&f=json&outfields=AddNum,StName,StType,City,Region,Postal,Country&text=5%20Barron%20Way,%20Eastman,%20Georgia,%20USA
```

which returns this result

```
{"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":4326},"locations":[{"name":"Barron Way, Eastman, Georgia, 31023","extent":{"xmin":-83.145949999999999,"ymin":32.172302000000002,"xmax":-83.139949999999999,"ymax":32.178302000000002},"feature":{"geometry":{"x":-83.14294854543823,"y":32.17530230405913},"attributes":{"AddNum":"","StName":"Barron","StType":"Way","City":"Eastman","Region":"Georgia","Postal":"31023","Country":"USA"}}}]}
```

which as you can see does not contain the full address that the suggest REST endpoint told me about. Has anyone encountered this before? Are there any workarounds? I don't want to provide a suggestion to my end users only to find that it can't be used because the find endpoint doesn't return the address suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your request to suggest has category filtering while your find suggest does not.

I have found ESRI category filtering and magic keys to be very finicky.